# Read DataBase after JavascriptInterface

Tags: java, android, database

I am designing an app. I want to read the database after running the javascript I appointed. The problem is how should I define the database when running javascript?

Here is the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DataBaseHelper myDB;
    private WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDB = new DataBaseHelper(this); // This is my DataBase

        default_data();
        display_html();
        run_javascript();
    }

    public void default_data()
    {   Cursor res = myDB.getAllData();
        if (res.getCount() == 0) {
            boolean isInserted = myDB.insertData("duty_selection_area ", "flex");
        }
    }

    public void display_html()
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    public void run_javascript()
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
    }
}
```

DataBaseHelper Part

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student2.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student_table2";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "HTML_Element";
    public static final String COL_3 = "State";

    public DataBaseHelper(@Nullable MainActivity context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, HTML_Element TEXT, State TEXT) ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String HTML_Element, String state)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, HTML_Element);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, state);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " +  TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }

    public Integer deleteData(String id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] { id });
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id, String name, String surname, String marks)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, surname);

        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "id = ?", new String[] { id });
        return true;
    }
}
```

JavaScriptInterface

```
public class JavaScriptInterface
{
    DataBaseHelper myDB;

    Context mContext;

    JavaScriptInterface(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface

    public String showDataBase()
    {
        myDB = new DataBaseHelper((MainActivity) mContext);
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        Cursor res = myDB.getAllData();

        if (res.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while (res.moveToNext())
            {
                buffer.append("Id: " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                buffer.append("HTML_Element: " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                buffer.append("State: " + res.getString(2) + "\n\n");
            }
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

And this is my index.html

```
<input type="button" value="Get from android" onclick="showDataBase()">
<label class="duty_selection_font"> Check Data Base </label>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVar = null;
    function showDataBase() {
        myVar = Android.showDataBase();
        alert(myVar);
    }
</script>
```

What I do is firstly write some default data to the database when the app is installed. This part is run smoothly. Then run the index.html in the asset folder. This part is also run smoothly. However, problem occurs when I click the button in the index.html to return the data(in string) from database (DataBaseHelper). It simply stops immediately. What should I do?

I try to search in google but nothing similar matches.

Comment: You need to look at the LogCat to find the stacktrace. There will be an exception thrown there with a useful message

Comment: Thank you Ivan. I think it is a typo mistake in the script. I fix it after doing some changes.